# php mysql query doesn't send date and time types null to insert

Tags: php, mysql

I looked at similar questions but I can't solve the problem. I have 2 different columns with types date and time in MySql. I use explode to split date from time. The split code is the following ;

```
$task_date_time = $data['task_date_time'];

if($task_date_time != "")
{           
    $date_time = explode(" ", $task_date_time); // split according to the delimiter
    $task_date = $date_time[0];         
    $task_time = $date_time[1];         
}
else
{           
    $task_date = NULL;
    $task_time = NULL;          
}
```

After that, I am calling the php function that inserts this variables to MySQL database. My query inside the data function is the following ;

```
$query = "call insertProcedure(...some variables...,  ".$task_date.", ".$task_time.")";
```

However, query gives the following error ;

```
Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':48)' at line 1
```

- The `':48)'` field corresponds to minute field of time type.

Notes :

1) I also tried the query string below. it doesn't work either

```
$query = "call insertProcedure(...some variables...,  '".$task_date."', '".$task_time."')";
```

2) `$task_date` and `$task_time` are nullable in MySQL database.

Any ideas ? Solutions ?

Comment: Can you provide an example d/t string?

Comment: Could you echo out $query of the one you posted in 'Notes' point 1? I am curious what the query itself is, maybe you're looking for the problem in the wrong place.

Comment: task_date_time is simply a json variable. for instance, "20/02/2012 22:48"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it should be `NULL`:

```
$task_date = 'NULL';
$task_time = 'NULL';
```

You're setting the variables to `NULL`, which when cast to a string will produce an empty string.  And mysql fails to parse it.

If you set the variables to the string `'NULL'` mysql will correctly set the columns to be `NULL`

And when it should have a real value, the date and time need to be surrounded by quotes.  e.g.:

```
$task_date = "'".$date_time[0]."'";         
$task_time = "'".$date_time[1]."'";
```

Comment: it's almost correct but date field is null when I enter a date which is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Your query string is not properly surrounded by quotes, I believe you need to place quotes around your $task_date and $task_time, since they currently seem to not validate in the query string. Try these:

```
$query = 'call insertProcedure(...some variables...,  "'.$task_date.'", "'.$task_time.'")';

$query = "call insertProcedure(...some variables...,  '".$task_date."', '".$task_time."')";
```

EDIT: Apparently you already tried that. But the error should be different in that case, was it?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL expects a time to be in format "HH:mm:ss", you are not including seconds, and so need to append the ':00' on the end i.e.

```
$query = "CALL insertProcedure(...some variables...,  '".$task_date."'), '".$task_time.":00')";
```

You can see this yourself by doing the following query manually

```
SELECT TIME('12:34') AS fails, TIME('12:34:00') AS succeeds;
```

Comment: I tried that query. if date and time both not null, date is correct, but time is 00:00. if they're both null, date is correct, time is 00:00

Comment: Added logic to deal with the timestamp conversion + added falling back to MySQL to split TIME and DATE segments

Comment: I don't need to split date field again. my sql procedure handles that with STR_TO_DATE format conversion, but thank you :D

Comment: Moreover, the type isn't DATETIME. We use date & time types seperately

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's DATETIME, DATE() extracts the date portion, and TIME() extracts the time portion, just saves splitting it out in the first place but if you've STR_TO_DATE doing that already it's not an issue.  Will update it to just have the :00 then, as I did a test and TIME('12:34') returns NULL while TIME('12:34:00') returns '12:34:00' TIME value